# Can I list several keys to perform the same action? [AHK]

Tags: autohotkey

AHK allows to bind keys, that is us `a::z` t fire 'z' whenever 'a' is pressed.
What if I want to fire 'z' whenever 'a', 'b', or 'c' is pressed?

I can obviously repeat my code:

```
  a::z
  b::z
  c::z
```

I can probably use a Gosub like

```
a::Gosub, abc
b::Gosub, abc
c::Gosub, abc

abc:
send z
return
```

Is there a better way to say "if a,b, or c are pressed - fire z"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
a::
b::
c::z
```

i am not sure what is the exact synthax, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

We're at codegolf.stackexchange.com, right?

JFF, here's assigning <kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to Z with just 61 characters, using the [Hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command:

```c
loop,25
    hotkey,% chr(a_index+64),z
return
z(){ 
    send z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [`Hotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) to define hotkeys on the fly, and `parse` so that the user can directly specify a list of keys:

```
; Thanks engunneer: autohotkey.com/board/topic/45636-script-to-prevent-double-typing/?p=284048
; Thanks throwaway_ye: https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/54g40q/how_can_i_bind_several_keys_to_the_same_command/d81j0we

; The following part must be located in the auto-execute section, 
; i.e. the top part of the AHK script.

keylist = 1234567890qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm

Loop, parse, keylist
{
  Hotkey, $%A_LoopField%, SendGivenKey
}    
Return


; This can be located anywhere in the AHK file
SendGivenKey:
StringReplace, key, A_ThisHotkey, $, , All
send %key%
Return
```